# How to change size of button dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I tried the `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` methods, but they do not work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using LayoutParams. For example

`button.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams(50, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`

Answer (score 10):

For me works perfect this:

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myButton.getLayoutParams();
    //Button new width
    params.width = 400;

    myButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this to be the best solution because it also allows the button to be repositioned at the same time by simply changing its margin:

```
int buttonWidth = (int) (screenWidth / 3.0);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) myButton.getLayoutParams();
params.width = buttonWidth;
params.leftMargin = buttonWidth;
myButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```