# Change height of android button through code

Tags: java, android, button, runtime

I am trying to change the height and width of a button through code at runtime.

**My layout xml**

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@drawable/button1_background" 
    />
```

**Main activity code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   //some other code
   int displaywidth= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    Button f_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Log.d("F_button width before is",""+ f_button.getWidth());
    f_button.setWidth(displaywidth/2);
    Log.d("F_button width after is",""+ f_button.getWidth());
//some other code
}
```

The Logcat shows both F_button after and before width as "0".

what am I doing wrong.

thanks!.

Comment: Do the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472445/how-to-change-size-of-button-dynamic-in-android help?

Answer (score 3):

i think it might help you..

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1); 

android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,60); // 60 is height you can set it as u need

btn.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
int displaywidth= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;    
ViewGroup.LayoutParams buttonlp= (ViewGroup.LayoutParams)f_button.getLayoutParams();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(displaywidth, buttonlp.height);
buttonlp.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Instead of `LinearLayout` you should use the parent layout of the button if it is not `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried to solve the problem for a long time. Ajay's solution made me successful.
For Kotlin programmers it looks like this:

```
btn.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 60)
```