# How to programmatically change size of my button?

Tags: android

How to programmatically change size of my button with code on android (in run time)?

Comment: pls post what have you tried .

Comment: May you be more precise please ? Which code do you have tried ? Why does it not work ?

Comment: Seriously ?  http://bit.ly/1bAmFFM

Comment: Shall we code for you

Comment: Hello user2975767, to get a positive response here, you should show what you have tried. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is best. Don't ask people to vote your questions up; that usually has the opposite effect.

Comment: First google for the problem before asking on here, performing a google search shows tonnes of examples of what you could try. If you try the examples and still doesn't work, sure post a question on here, but include what you have tried, and explain where it is going wrong, if there are exceptions these should also be posted. Doing this will help build your repuation, asking question just in the hope of building your reputation, will likely have the opposite effect

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [how to change size of button dynamic in android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5472445/456814).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using LayoutParams

```
button.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams(60, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
button.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams(20, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 2):

use following code

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myButton.getLayoutParams();
//Button new width
params.width = 400;

myButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(YOUR WIDTH, YOUR HEIGHT));
```