# How do I make the foreground attribute for a button work below API 23?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, foreground

I have two `Buttons` nested in a `LinearLayout`. Between these `Buttons` are two `TextViews`. In the `Xml`, I have set the foreground to an image for each of these `Buttons`.

It runs fine on my device for `Api 23`. But on other devices below `Api 23`, the foreground image does not display and instead results in a default white solid color. Is there any way to make these images show using foreground below `Api 23`?

We have tried `FrameLayout` but it does not do what we want it to do. Would `ImageButtons` be a better way to solve this issue?

One of the core functions of our app is that every time a user taps a `Button`, the size increases and the image stretches accordingly. This is done dynamically in code. If I were to use `ImageButtons`, I would need to set the layout parameters every time for height and width, rather than one line of code that sets the height.

Any tips would be appreciated!

EDIT: Code I am working with -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="11"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:id="@+id/firstP"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:foreground="@drawable/icebutton"
        android:scaleX="1"
        android:scaleY="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:id="@+id/firstPlayer"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:id="@+id/secondPlayer"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:id="@+id/secondP"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:foreground="@drawable/firebutton"
        android:scaleX="1"
        android:scaleY="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please !

Comment: I have added the code I am working with. I am currently trying to implement `ImageButtons`
@Micho Thank you for the Edit. I'll make sure I format correctly in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We found out that there were two issues causing the images to not be shown.
1. The size of the image file was too big, creating an `outOfMemory` error which in turn resulted in the buttons not displaying the images.
2. The foreground attribute does not work for API 22 and below.

Steps to solving these issues:
1. We reduced the size of the image files. 
2. We replaced `Button` with `ImageButton` 
3. In the `XML` file we removed the foreground attribute, added a black background, and added the image via the `src` attribute. The following is a snippet.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:id="@+id/firstP"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:src="@drawable/icebutton"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

4. We then had to change our code to dynamically adjust the height of the buttons to match the new image buttons with the help of this link by setting the `LayoutParams`: 
   [how to change size of button dynamic in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472445/how-to-change-size-of-button-dynamic-in-android)

Now everything works perfectly!

Comment: API 22! That was my issue. Was running 21 for testing. Thank you.