# How to dynamically change button size?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to make the size of both button equal but as I change the screen below button size increase as you can see in the Image.

[Click here to view Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJOEl.png)

**Here is the Code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:context=".Timer">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/player1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#696969"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textSize="95sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/player1">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_pause_circle_outline_24"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/player2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#696969"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textSize="95sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472445/how-to-change-size-of-button-dynamic-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LinearLayout as parent and provide with weight to children to achieve the result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Timer">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/player1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#696969"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:textSize="95sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_pause_circle_outline_24"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/player2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#696969"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:textSize="95sp" />
```

Comment: It worked, but can you tell me how Linear Layout weights work?

Comment: Okay. You can specify weightSum to your parent linear layout using `android:weightSum="10"`. by default the weightSum is one. This weight can be distributed among the child views of LinearLayout according to the orientation. For example, If you want to place two button horizontally, create a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation, containing two buttons, add android:layout_weight="0.5" to each button. See more here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear#Weight

Comment: Thanks, I have understood it.