# Android: looks good while editing, bad on emulator - why

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:text="People:"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="27dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:text="Amount:"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="27dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="125dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#D9D9D9"
        android:text="CALCULATE"
        android:textColor="#323232"
        app:backgroundTint="#CCCCCC"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="138dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="193dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="162dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="38dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="162dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="104dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**:

[image]

**EDIT**:

```
  <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="30dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="353dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="196dp"
        >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: That is because you have given static height * width to your controls.

Comment: @KaranMehta How do I fix it? I tried making `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` but it didn't work

Comment: I have just answered @parsecer, Please check that

Answer (score 1):

This issue is happening because you have given static height * width to your controls so now first of all please implement this library from this link : [https://github.com/intuit/sdp#:~:text=SDP%20%2D%20a%20scalable%20size%20unit,sp%20size%20unit%20for%20texts](https://github.com/intuit/sdp#:%7E:text=SDP%20%2D%20a%20scalable%20size%20unit,sp%20size%20unit%20for%20texts).

And then copy and paste below code and you can change size according to UI that you want to make but you will have to give size like this only : "@dimen/_XXsdp" like given in below code.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_26sdp"
        android:text="People:"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="@dimen/_27sdp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="@dimen/_50sdp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_79sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:text="Amount:"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="27dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="125dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#D9D9D9"
        android:text="CALCULATE"
        android:textColor="#323232"
        app:backgroundTint="#CCCCCC"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="@dimen/_138sdp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="@dimen/_193sdp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="@dimen/_162sdp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="@dimen/_38sdp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="@dimen/_162sdp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="@dimen/_104sdp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It's not possible without third-party library?

Comment: For that you will have to do R&D and then find some solution for this issue but let me tell you one thing that this library is very light weight and won't have much effect on your app size.

Comment: I can't use third party libraries. And I want to understand how to do it without them.

Comment: For that check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472445/how-to-change-size-of-button-dynamic-in-android or https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Answer (score 1):

When you put this .xml on Android Studio, you get this explicit warning:

> This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it
> will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints

Remenber you are using a ConstraintLayout, try this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="People:"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView14"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editTextNumber10"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Amount:"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editTextNumber11"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:background="#D9D9D9"
        android:text="CALCULATE"
        android:textColor="#323232"
        app:backgroundTint="#CCCCCC"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextNumber11" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView13"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView13" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextNumber10" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please see edit. It works, but if the screen is too narrow the input labels are lost

Comment: You are using some extreme margins like: android:layout_marginBottom="697dp" maybe is a typo, i edited my answer againg, but fix those margins

Comment: Thanks so much! It works! May I ask you - I've been watching this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUmXfTI-ojY - and it uses `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`. Are those preferable in my case over `ConstraintLayout`? I've only been using `ConstraintLayout`, because it was the default

Comment: Personally i would use Linear Layout it's faster to render in most of the cases, but please have a read at this post first, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321448/differences-between-constraintlayout-and-relativelayout

Also, don't forget to check as accepted answer to help others.

Comment: Could you please see my last edit? ; ( I tried to add a `TableLayout` with two buttons, I set `marginTop` to `196dp` but it didn't work. Removing `absoluteX/absoluteY` makes the table to appear in the upper left corner even in the editor itself

Comment: You clearly don't understand how ConstraintLayout works, please read the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

I suggest changing your root layour to LinearLayour which is easier until you learn your basics